# Textfield Background Image size

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiimage, uitextfield

I want to set textfield background image same as Default contact app.

Is there any built-in type for that?

If I take the custom image then what size should be taken? because iPad has variable length of textfield.

Comment: Try this
`textfield.borderStyle =UITextBorderStyleNone;

textfield.background=[UIImage imageNamed:@"txt2.jpg"];`

Comment: @Proton, what is the size of txt2.jpg?

Comment: You can refer this https://github.com/stavash/SAHighlightedTextField

Answer (score 0):

You change the two way one is code used to change

```
UITextField *textField;
    textField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

Another one way is you to change in text property at attribute inspector [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to strech image from center and place as `textfield.background`.

`[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];`

You can also refers this from [link.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets)

Also [here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-uiimage-and-resizableimagewithcapinsets.html) is the best example.